# Are there any CEFs of UK stocks for the US investor?

Tags: united-states, stocks, united-kingdom

Are there any Closed-End Funds (CEFs, I'm NOT looking for ETFs) available in the USA that invest solely in UK stocks? In particular, are there any lean toward the small-caps and/or dividends?

I have the hardest time searching out CEFs.

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn’t buy a UK investment trust, traded on the London Stock Exchange?

Comment: @marktristan accessibility, I suppose. I don't think I have access to the London Stock Exchange via my broker. Owning shares on a foreign exchange is something I've never done.